# MySQL query returns images in a grid

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In my code I use this MySQL query:

```
 $qry="SELECT ServiceIcon FROM Services INNER JOIN UserServices ON UserServices.ServiceID=Services.ServiceID WHERE UserServices.UserID=$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]";
 $result=mysql_query($qry);

 header("Content-type: image/png");
 echo mysql_result($result,0);
```

I want these images to be displayed in a grid of 3 icons wide. Currently they're displayed on top of each other however. So I should echo an  like this:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo '<li><img src="' . $image['src'] . '" id="' . $image['id'] . '" /></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

What I don't understand is how I should incorporate into my code. Or maybe my code is not even the right way to do it. Please help me out.

EDIT: So this is the complete file in question:

```
<?php
 session_start();   
 include "connection.php";
 // just so we know it is broken
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 // some basic sanity checks

 $qry="SELECT ServiceIcon FROM Services INNER JOIN UserServices ON UserServices.ServiceID=Services.ServiceID WHERE UserServices.UserID=$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]";
 $result=mysql_query($qry);

 header("Content-type: image/png");


?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul.horizontal-display {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul.horizontal-display li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo '<ul class="horizontal-display">';
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo '<li><img src="' . $result . '" id="' . $image['id'] . '" /></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to apply proper CSS styling to the `<ul>` in order for the images to display as you want them.

Comment: @Floris But is the $images as $image part correct, since I use that nowhere else?

Comment: Well if you never define $images then obviously it's not going to work. I was under the assumption that there was more to your code than just this.

Comment: I added the complete code of this particular file in the main question...

Answer (score 1):

Hello you need to add CSS. Something like this:

```
echo '<ul class="horizontal-display">';
foreach ($images as $image) {
echo '<li><img src="' . $image['src'] . '" id="' . $image['id'] . '" /></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

And in the CSS rules

```
ul.horizontal-display {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.horizontal-display li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: li tags have the display propertie as list-item you need to change them to inline or inline-block so that they are display in horizontal

Comment: Thanks that really helped! 
But what I'm curious about; is the '$images as $image' part correct, because I never define or use them anywhere else?